# What is the reason behind `stack_chk_fail` being undefined?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, glibc

AFAIK, __stack_chk_fail is a standard library function that is run when stack smashing is detected. If a binary is compiled with -fstack-protector, it will just link to it just like printf? So how is `undefined reference to symbol '__stack_chk_fail@@GLIBC_2.4'` even possible?

Comment: "is a standard library function". Which standard defines it?

Comment: It does not appear in the C18 standard doc - edit - two different languages are tagged!

Comment: It's definitely not a standard function, it's a common extension though.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/debug/stack_chk_fail.c.html
which kind of function is it then?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli it said nothing about *why* it could be undefined.

Comment: @Discape really? The first line of the accepted answer is *libgurobi_c++.a was compiled with -fno-stack-protector (obviously)*. In any case, it's impossible to say anything if you just post the error without anything else that might help [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it.

Comment: It is a non-standard function. That's what kind of function it is.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli > libgurobi_c++.a was compiled with -fno-stack-protector 
then why is it trying to reference __stack_chk_fail if it doesn't even have a stack protector. And why would it not be able to be found in glibc?

Comment: "Why would it not be able to be found in glibc"  This question has a very easy answer: because it is not there. Or, at any rate, the *requested version* of the symbol is not there. It may or may not contain an older version.

Comment: @Discape well, if you are linking a piece of code that was compiled with stack protector with another that was not, then you can get this error.. but that depends. It could also be a version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the binary is either not linking with glibc (this can happen if you use `ld` as your linker and forget to link libc, use `c++` or `cc` to link instead), or there is a version mismatch.